# Uniswap 'INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY' on testnet

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to get estimated eth needed to perform a swap on ropsten.

```
interface IUniswap {
            
        function WETH() external pure returns (address);
        
        function getAmountsOut(
            uint amountIn, 
            address[] calldata path)
            external
            view 
            returns (uint[] memory amounts);        
}


contract UniswapController {
    address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;

    IUniswap public uniswapRouter;

    address private UNISWAP_DAI_ADDRESS = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;

    constructor() public {
        uniswapRouter = IUniswap(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
    }

    function getEstimatedETHforToken(uint daiAmount) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        return uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI());

    }
    
    function getWETH() public view returns(address) {
        return uniswapRouter.WETH();
    }
    
    function getPathForETHtoDAI() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        
        path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
        path[1] = UNISWAP_DAI_ADDRESS;
    
        return path;
    }
}
```

When I run `getEstimatedETHforToken(amount)` on remix ide, I get the error:

`execution reverted: UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY`

I suspect I have the wrong DAI stablecoin address, but this is the address on uniswap's site, which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be good tokens use on testnets. Just forked the mainnet using `ganache-cli` and infura with [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@samajammin/how-to-interact-with-ethereums-mainnet-in-a-development-environment-with-ganache-3d8649df0876) and it worked just fine.